# How do I repair html hinting

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

On one of my vscode installations html hints I working fine (when in html mode I type lin I see this>[image]

on another only the first line and none of the html link hints. What I did

- removed all extention
- reinstalled visual studio code in place
- removed and reinstall visual studion code

I don't see anything suspicious in the debug pane.

How do I repair my VSCode?

Comment: Try dragging down on the lower border of the suggestions box.

Answer (score 0):

Life saver Mark <3. Thanks!

It is a bit fiddly, but indeed the hints box can be sized to a useless single line size. As I see no real use case for this it could be regarded as bug.

- Drag the upper or lower border up or down.
- To increase success increase zoom size.

Comment: It is a bug, should be fixed in this week's update.